# How to detect imaginary fit outcomes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am fitting data in MATLAB using: `modelFun = @(B,x) B(1) + (B(2)-B(1)).*(1-exp(-B(3)*x))`, which is a 'one-phase association' function. The input data are all real integers, between 0 and 100.

The fitting is done with `B = lsqcurvefit(modelFun,start,nx,ny,lb,ub);`
nx and ny are the number of x and y values
lb and ub are the constraints (outcomes of B1 and B2 should be between 0 and 100%, B3 is unconstrained)

All works well, but every now and then, MATLAB returns an error:

> Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored.
>
> > In script (line xxx)

What I understand from this, is that the fit output is stripped from the imaginary parts and the real numbers are saved. I'm  truly a math newbie, but my gut feeling tells me that the fit should always yield real numbers, at least, that's what I want.

Now, I simply want to be able to detect automatically when the fit outputs imaginary numbers, such that I can throw away these fit outcomes and discard them. However, because MATLAB immediately makes the fit output parameters real, my solution to the problem, *i.e*., check the outcome B for imaginary numbers, won't work:

```
if ~isreal(B) %check whether any component in the fit outcome is imaginary
    [actions, like delete the parameter B] 
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably see how good the fit is, and base any decisions on that. You should not rely on implementation details.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - quite frankly, I do not care too much how good the fit is; the data are pretty poor to begin with.  To have a fit that approaches the data is good enough for the purpose.

Comment: Then why does it matter if the fit function produced a complex component and then discarded it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I am a math newbie, and I should have given more background, perhaps. Thing is, the input data are real integers between 0 - 100 and represent % scores on speech tests. It's not rocket science, basically psychophysics. The numbers that should come out of the fit should represent values, or derivatives reflective of  real integer values between 0 and 100%. In a nut shell, I don't really grasp imaginary numbers, other than that it's useful to calculate AC power output, if I remember correctly... I'm just a Biologist, kill me gently....

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like that:

```
% Here is the warning that you want to catch
targWarn = 'Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored';

if strcmp(lastwarn, targWarn)
  % do whatever you would like to do with parameter B
end
```

*Unrelated to your primary question*: You may want to explore more whether if throwing away the complex answer is necessary or not.

Comment: This was really helpful. Still working on implementing it. Accept may follow :)